# Verificar se existem campos iguais em um form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um form com 5 `selects` e estou tentando verificar se algum desses selects estão com o mesmo valor.

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    var $commitment = $("[name='commitment']").val();
    var $proActivity = $("[name='proActivity']").val();
    var $superation = $("[name='superation']").val();
    var $teamWork = $("[name='teamWork']").val();
    var $planningAndOrganization = $("[name='planningAndOrganization']").val();

    Object.prototype.in = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
            if (arguments[i] == this) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Porém quando preciso validar meu `IF` fica gigantesco;

```
    if ($commitment.in($proActivity, $superation, $teamWork, $planningAndOrganization) ||
        $proActivity.in($commitment, $superation, $teamWork, $planningAndOrganization) ||
        $superation.in($commitment, $proActivity, $teamWork, $planningAndOrganization) ||
        $teamWork.in($commitment, $proActivity, $superation, $planningAndOrganization) ||
        $planningAndOrganization.in($commitment, $proActivity, $superation, $teamWork)) {
        $('.alert').show();

        return false;
    }
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa verificação usando o próprio DOM do form?

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia verificar o valor de cada option e desabilitar os que possuem o mesmo valor, dessa forma o usuário só poderia adicionar opções diferentes:

```js
$("form > select").change(function() {
  $("form > select > option").prop("disabled", false);
  var elem = $("form > select").not("[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']");
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var options = document.getElementsByName(elem[i].name)[0].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
      if ($(this).val() == options[j].innerHTML) {
        options[j].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="commitment">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="proActivity">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="superation">
    <option></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

Exemplo:

```
function validSelectsValues() {
    var domSelects = 'Seus selects aqui';
    var selected = [];
    $(domSelect).each(function() {
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), selected)) {
            continue;
        }
        $.merge(selected, $(this).val());
    });

    return $(select).size() == $(domSelects).size();
}
```

Dessa forma, a quantidade de selects será iterada dinamicamente e você poderá ter 5 ou 100. A formula sempre vai pegar o valor do select iterado e atribuirá a um array que grava os valores selecionados caso o mesmo não tenha sido gravado anteriormente. Depois é só vc comparar se a quantidade de valores escritos nesse array é equivalente a quantidade de select existentes no seu seletor.

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma forma bem mais simples:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   var id =  $(this).attr('id');
   var valor = $(this).val();
   var selects = $('select').not('#' + id).find('option[value="' + valor + '"]:selected');
   if (selects.length > 0) {
      console.log('já selecionado');
   }
});
```

No exemplo, o seletor faz o seguinte:
Encontre todos os selects `$('select')` que **não** tenham certo id `not('#' + id)`, neste caso, o id do select que acabou de ser mudado, depois encontro todos que tenham um option com o mesmo valor `.find('option[value="' + valor + '"]` e que já estejam selecionados `:selected'`. Pronto.

Aqui um fiddle funcionando:  https://jsfiddle.net/06tatn2n/