# Como fazer para o select não permitir selecionar uma opção já selecionada em outro select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Como fazer com que o select **não permita** que o option "Lider" não seja **duplicado**, pois na minha regra de negócio **apenas um usuário pode ser líder**.

Eu pensei no seguinte:

Supondo que eu tenha 3 selects. Se eu selecionar um deles como **LÍDER**, e selecionar um outro select também como **LÍDER**, o javascript *deselecionava* a opção líder do primeiro select e deixaria selecionado apenas a opção Líder do segundo select.

Aqui está uma simulação do problema:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Não é resposta pra pergunta, mas não seria mais simples um radiobutton pra definir o lider? Ou tres colunas com nomes, sendo a primeira lider, select simples, e as outras duas select multiplo para conhecimento e participante.

Comment: Seria interessante também @Bacco, porém na documentação não é permitido radiobutton... preciso fazer de fato com selects...

Comment: Seria isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168517/32827

Comment: Muito próximo disso @LucasCosta, porém desativaria apenas a opção de value "1". Mas já ajudou bastante. Obigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve o seu problema:

```
$(".selectpicker").on("change", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var values = self.val();

    $(".selectpicker").not(self).each(function() {
        var _values = $(this).val();
        for (var v = _values.length; v--;) {
            if (values.indexOf(_values[v]) >= 0) {
                _values.splice(v, 1);
            }
        }

        $(this).val(_values);
    });
});
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda! Me deu um grande avanço. Porém alguns selects ainda estão permitindo ter dois selects... dá uma olhada https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/5t8noxne/

Comment: isso acontece porque é necessário executar o refresh no plugin após as mudanças, segue correção: https://jsfiddle.net/5t8noxne/1/

Comment: Verdade,@AndreNato. Eu havia colocado o refresh no canto errado.

Comment: Agora um último pedido de ajuda se vc puder: como impedir que o select que for selecionado como "Líder" não possua mais de uma função? Apenas a de líder?

Comment: como assim? o cara que for líder, não vai poder ter outra função?

Comment: isso mesmo, quem for líder não pode ter outra função

Comment: ok! de uma olhada, https://jsfiddle.net/5t8noxne/4/

Comment: Muito Obrigado! O resultado esperado era isso mesmo!